# table in html bootstrap not fitting in to screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, html-table

I have a table in html bootstrap, the table looks fit when the page loads, but after the page loads fully the table becomes scrollable

My code is:

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-borderd" id="orderTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>S.No</th>
        <th>Order ID</th>
        <th>Ordered By</th>
        <th>Branch name</th>
        <th>Order Date </th>
        <th>Order Time </th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Invoice Status</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr class="sn">
        <th>S.No</th>
        <th>Order ID</th>
        <th>Ordered By</th>
        <th>Branch name</th>
        <th>Order Date </th>
        <th>Order Time </th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Invoice Status</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>

    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Can anyone please tell me how to make it fit to the screen and avoid the scrolling. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show your whole code, please? Only these codes work correctly and the table isn't scrollable on my machine.

Comment: @Zubair: Peace! You have some other CSS being applied for the table. Share you code on codepen. Will need to check the issue. I checked it there in no scroll.

Comment: @George the datas are coming from database

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather can u please open a chat room

Comment: Wait Brother :) Let me open it and share the link

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226343/room-for-imran-rafiq-rather-and-zubair-nazer-oliyat

Comment: @ZubairNazerOliyat Click the above link to start chat

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather i have clicked

Comment: @ZubairNazerOliyat try `table-condensed` class along with `table-responsive`

Comment: @abdullahQureshee tried, no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, Main issue in this case is the width of the `<input/>` elements which was making all our columns follow the same width.

I have solved it with the following CSS for `Desktop Screen`.  For smaller screens, it is best to have the scroll for us to not loose any of our data.

```
@media (min-width:1320px{  
    tfoot th input {
        width: 90px !important;
    }
}
```

Later you can adjust this for even larger screen break point as per your requirement.